# Калькулятор с отображением площади на php и js

Tags: javascript

Нужно сделать похожий калькулятор http://www.gazetabaraholka.ru/reklamnyj_kalkulyator (нажмите на кнопку расчитать стоимость рекламы). Создатель решения на связь не выходит. Не могу понять, что находится в файле calculator.php как примерно выглядит код. Искал подобные решения чисто на js, ничего подобного не нашел.

JS:

/modules/zakaz/js/calc.js

/modules/zakaz/js/send_form.js

не понятно как связать отображение сетки php с файлами js что примерно находится внутри файла calculator.php (/modules/zakaz/calculator.php)

помогите хотябы куском кода)

Comment: никто не будет делать за вас работу, тут помогают когда столкнулись с проблемой, а вы рассказываете нам о файлах, которые мы не видим и в конце концов просите написать за вас хоть что-то

Comment: А что тут искать? Расчёт на чистом js - есть цена за см есть размер в см каждой полосы и выбирается количество полос и количество публикаций - просто перемножаете всё.

Comment: не понятно как на картинке странице сделать так чтобы площадь закрашивалась

Comment: тут тоже ответа не нашел)https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/622413/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-js?rq=1

Comment: @shura-shkura ответил ниже

Answer (score 0):

В расчёте используется формула:

Цена за см * ширину модуля * высоту модуля * количество публикаций - получаем итоговую стоимость.

Визуальное отображение сделано с помощью таблицы - после изменения параметров добавляется background-color для определённого количества строк и столбцов.